# Are the following identification spaces homotopy equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Consider two families $\{A_n\}$ and $\{B_n \}$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$, of circles in $\mathbb{R}^2$ centered at $0$. $A_n$ has radius $n$ and $B_n$ has radius $1/n$. Let $X \,$ (respectively $Y$) be the space $\mathbb{R}^2$ with all $A_n$ ($B_n$) identified.

> Are $X$ and $Y$ homotopy equivalent?

I do not know where to start. I see that they are not homeomorphic, so I suppose I need to find their fundamental groups, but how?

Comment: Observe that the relation in the $\{B_n\}$ is not closed, so the quotient is not Hausdorff. I would first see that this quotient is homotopy equivalent to the quotient obtained by the closure of the relation you're describing.

Comment: I also suggest to make a picture of what happens with the subset $\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ under this equivalence relation.